# .grass load error in nodes with whitespaces

Tags: neo4j, grass-file

How can I load a .grass file with node names with whitespaces?

For example:

```
node {
  diameter: 50px;
  color: #A5ABB6;
  border-color: #9AA1AC;
  border-width: 2px;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 10px;
}
node.* {
  color: #FF756E;
  border-color: #E06760;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  defaultCaption: "<id>";
}
node.Tecnología 3eros {
  defaultCaption: "<id>";
  color: #DE9BF9;
  border-color: #BF85D6;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
}
```

In node `Tecnología 3eros` I tried using `\` and quotes.

Comment: instead of defaultCaption: "<id>"; you can use instead of defaultCaption: '<id>';
 For example:

https://gist.github.com/xagronaut/b1ae6ca0009dcb3177f252af441fae17

Comment: have you try the back quote ? (ie. ` )

Comment: @logisima Yes, I get the same result.